# How to make request https to http?

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting

Basically First time I have hosted my website on cPanel with "https" enabled.

And my server code is in node.js which is running on. 
for ex:  **170.2.23.100:4100** is running perfectly.

Now my problem is while making request from my frontend which is : running on https://somesites.com can not able to make request to **node server**.

How to make request from https to http(backend in node.js) ?

Please some guide.

Comment: Which reverse proxy do you use? Basically you don't do any different than before but simply terminate https before forwarding upstream. You need to show your current configuration to help you find the mistake with terminating https.

Comment: I think best possible way is to run your node server in https

Comment: @khodayarJ great thanks. I used your way and it is working fine.

Comment: @DanFromGermany But I would wish to take your help how to setup reverse proxy in cPanel (Apache server). I don't know much more about server setup.

Comment: @khodayarJ  but there is a problem , it is asking for back to safety --> allow unsecure , then it works. any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DanFromGermany,

Ultimately I had to do **reverse proxy**.

Since when i tried to run node server in https, it was giving "Not Secure" , "Back to safety" like that errors in "Chrome" and also in "Mozila" request was not processed. So, finally i implemented **reverse proxy** to work.

Both solutions :

**Node server in https**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var https = require('https');

var httpsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../ssl/keys/','server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../ssl/certs/','server.crt'))
};


var server = https.createServer(httpsOptions,app).listen(port, host, function (request, response) {
  console.log("Server listening", host, port);
});
```

**Reverse Proxy setup using .htaccess:**

```
Header set "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://170.2.23.100:4100/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://170.2.23.100:4100/$1 [P,L]
```

May be it will help some.